# Session 'app': Error Installing APKs with :2.3.0-beta1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just updated my Android studio to 2.3 Beta 1. Now I am going to install an application, but it gives me this error:

> Error installing split apks: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException

My updated gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta1'
```

Comment: Turning off the instant run may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off the Instant run removed my error.